# SQL Pivot on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a query where I am pulling odds and football results:

```
SELECT
    Div, BookieResult, COUNT(BookieResult) AS WinLossCount, OddsCategory
FROM 
    [dbo].[MatchOutcomes]
GROUP BY
    div, OddsCategory, BookieResult
```

This returns a result like this:

[image]

I'm looking to get results where the data is more readable and each like is on a single line like:

[image]

I've been trying to pivot the data in many different ways but cant seem to get it in SQL. does anyone know if the layout above can be accomplished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it. Thanks for the help guys, they led me in the right direction

```
  select * from (
  Select Div, CONCAT(BookieResult,OddsCategory) as [fg], Count(BookieResult) as 
  WinLossCount
  FROM [dbo].[MatchOutcomes]
  group by div, OddsCategory, BookieResult) as s
  PIVOT
  (
  SUM(WinLossCount)
  FOR [fg] IN (
  Lose0,
Win0,
Lose1,
Win1,
Lose2,
Win2,
Lose3,
Win3)
) AS PVT
order by div desc
```

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J0iE.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH Table AS
(
  Select Div, BookieResult, Count(BookieResult) as WinLossCount, 
  OddsCategory
  FROM [dbo].[MatchOutcomes]
  group by div, OddsCategory, BookieResult
)
select Res1.Div
           ,Res1.[Loss]
           ,Res1.[Win]
           ,Res1.[oddscategory]
           ,Res2.[Loss]
           ,Res2.[Win]
           ,Res2.[oddscategory]
           ,Res3.[Loss]
           ,Res3.[Win]
           ,Res3.[oddscategory] 
           ,Res4.[Loss]
           ,Res4.[Win]
           ,Res4.[oddscategory]
    from
    (
    select Div
               ,[Loss]
               ,[Win]
               ,[oddscategory]
        from Table
        pivot
        (
             max(winlosscount)
             for BookResult IN ([Loose],[Win])
        )Rs1
        where oddscategory = 0 
     )Res1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    select Div
               ,[Loss]
               ,[Win]
               ,[oddscategory]
        from Table
        pivot
        (
             max(winlosscount)
             for BookResult IN ([Loose],[Win])
        )Rs2
        where oddscategory = 1 
     )Res2 ON Res2.Div = Res1.Div
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    select Div
               ,[Loss]
               ,[Win]
               ,[oddscategory]
        from Table
        pivot
        (
             max(winlosscount)
             for BookResult IN ([Loose],[Win])
        )Rs3
        where oddscategory = 2 
     )Res3 Res3.Div = Res1.Div
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    select Div
               ,[Loss]
               ,[Win]
               ,[oddscategory]
        from Table
        pivot
        (
             max(winlosscount)
             for BookResult IN ([Loose],[Win])
        )Rs4
        where oddscategory = 3 
     )Res4 Res4.Div = Res1.Div
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried like below as you have two modifications odd from your current to desired o/p those are the `BookieResult

(Loss/Win)` and the last one be the `OddsCategory as(0,1,2,3)` likewise pivoted to only these columns to reflect the current. hope it works for you.

```
       Select Div, BookieResult, 
       WinLossCount, OddsCategory from
        (Select Div, BookieResult, Count(BookieResult) as 
       WinLossCount, OddsCategory
      FROM [dbo].[MatchOutcomes]
      group by div, OddsCategory, BookieResult)

        PIVOT
          (
   Count(BookieResult) as 
     WinLossCount, OddsCategory
   for OddsCategory IN (0,1,2,3) And 
      BookieResult IN ("Loss","Win")
     )

   )
```